# How can I give a class as argument to a Python function

Tags: python

I have two functions in my (first!) Python program that only differ by the class that must be instanciated.

```
def f(id):
    c = ClassA(id)
    ...
    return ...

def g(id):
    c = ClassB(id)
    ...
    return ...
```

To avoid repeated code, I would like to be able to write a single function that would somehow accept the class to instanciate as a parameter.

```
def f(id):
    return f_helper(id, ... ClassA ...)

def g(id):
    return f_helper(id, ... ClassB ...)

def f_helper(id, the_class):
    c = ... the_class ... (id)
    ...
    return ...
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible, but did not find how...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That works exactly as you have it (minus the `...`s):

```
>>> class foo:
    pass

>>> def make_it(cls):
    return cls()

>>> make_it(foo)
<__main__.foo instance at 0x011D9B48>
```

This can be modified to take in/pass params to the class constructor as well if you like, but the idea is perfectly fine.  Classes are first-class objects in Python.

Answer (score 4):

You pretty much got it right, just drop the dots. Classes are first-class values, you can just refer to them, as to any object. `f` would be `return f_helper(id, ClassA)` and `g` would be `return f_helper(id, ClassB)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callable to a function; a class itself is a callable, the returned object being an instance of said class.

```
def f_helper(id, the_class):
    c = the_class(id)
    # ...
    return # ...
```